# CWE-89: Improper Neutralization of Special Elements used in an SQL Command ('SQL Injection')

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I'm getting the following warning:

> CWE-89: Improper Neutralization of Special Elements used in an SQL Command ('SQL Injection') exception at insertCount = aBatchPstmt.executeBatch(); SQL injections can be prevented by using parameterised query

I believe I followed the recommendation but I still see the same message. 
 How do I fix this?

```
    int[] insertCount = null;
    if (stmtLogList.size() > 0) {
        Connection dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        PreparedStatement aBatchPstmt = null;
        try {

            String anInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO " + getDBName() + ".dbo."
                    + "statementGenerationlog  (CountryCode,CIFNumber,FileName,ZipFilename,Status,BatchRunDate,logDesc,FileType) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            aBatchPstmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(anInsertQuery);
            for (StatementGenerationLogBean aLogDetails : stmtLogList) {
                aBatchPstmt.setString(1, aLogDetails.getCountryCode());
                aBatchPstmt.setString(2, aLogDetails.getCifNumber());
                aBatchPstmt.setString(3, aLogDetails.getFileName());
                aBatchPstmt.setString(4, aLogDetails.getZipFileName());
                aBatchPstmt.setInt(5, aLogDetails.getStatus());
                aBatchPstmt.setString(6, aLogDetails.getBatchRunDate());
                aBatchPstmt.setString(7, aLogDetails.getLogDesc());
                aBatchPstmt.setString(8, aLogDetails.getFileType());
                aBatchPstmt.addBatch();
            }
            insertCount = aBatchPstmt.executeBatch();

        } finally {
            closeDB(dbConnection);
            closePreparedStatement(aBatchPstmt);
        }
    }
    return insertCount;

}
```

Comment: Step 1: describe what you did.  For example, I ran scanner tool blammyHooty and it says that I have a booboo.  Step 2. consider adding the code (you did that).

Comment: *Any* time you're using string concatenation to build out your query, you're vulnerable to injection.  How can you guarantee that `getDBName()` isn't compromised to return such a statement?

Comment: @DwB:  The question's fairly straightforward; an edit will likely fix your main complaint...

Comment: @Makoto Even when I hardcoe the DBname still error occurs. Noticed that when I pass prepared staement in to try block error rectifies but if i do in that way I can't close the preparedstatement in finally block:(.Please help.